# MergeSort vs. antialising rule

Tags: fortran, language-lawyer, mergesort, array-merge, fortran95

I have the following implementation of the MergeSort algorithm in Fortran.

My question is about `call merge(work(1 : half), A(half + 1:), A)`.
Obviously I have overlapping memory, but from looking at the code in `merge`, this should be no problem, as long as the input arrays are sorted. (Which they are assumed to be anyway.)

On the other hand Fortran compilers may assume non aliased memory,
so I always think "don't do this".

I have two questions now:

1. When and how can I run into problems with my `merge` subroutine.
2. If I cannot implement `MergeSort` like this, how do I do it without creating a temporary array.

```
!> Merge sorted arrays A and B into C while preversing order.
        subroutine merge(A, B, C)
        implicit none
        integer, intent(in) :: A(:), B(:)
        integer, intent(inout) :: C(:)

        integer :: i, j, k

        if (size(A) + size(B) > size(C)) abort

        i = 1; j = 1
        do k = 1, size(C)
          if (i <= size(A) .and. j <= size(B)) then
            if (A(i) <= B(j)) then
              C(k) = A(i)
              i = i + 1
            else
              C(k) = B(j)
              j = j + 1
            end if
          else if (i <= size(A)) then
            C(k) = A(i)
            i = i + 1
          else if (j <= size(B)) then
            C(k) = B(j)
            j = j + 1
          end if
        end do
      end subroutine merge

      recursive subroutine MergeSort(A, work)
        implicit none
        integer, intent(inout) :: A(:)
        integer, intent(inout) :: work(:)

        integer :: half
        half = (size(A) + 1) / 2
        if (size(A) < 2) then
          continue
        else if (size(A) == 2) then
          call naive_sort(A)
        else
          call MergeSort(A( : half), work)
          call MergeSort(A(half + 1 :), work)
          if (A(half) > A(half + 1)) then
            work(1 : half) = A(1 : half)
! TODO: Non aliasing rule.
            call merge(work(1 : half), A(half + 1:), A)
          endif
        end if
      end subroutine MergeSort
```

PS: As you perhaps notice, the array C in the `merge` subroutine is declared as an `inout` parameter, because it is later used with overlapping memory.

Comment: It is probably problematic, no time to check the details. Better to use the `target` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

This use of aliasing in calling `merge` is erroneous.

With

```
call merge(work(1 : half), A(half + 1:), A)
```

the dummy argument `B` is associated with `A(half+1:)` and the dummy argument `C` with `A` which is the understood overlap.

This aliasing means that the elements of `B` may not be defined (which is additionally required by the intent) and that the last few elements of `C` may not be defined.

However, if we look at the main loop in `merge` we see that in general every element of `C` appears in a statement looking like `C(k)=...`: we expect at least one of those conditions inside to be true.  This is therefore invalid.

To be clear: a statement like `C(k)=B(j)` would be an illegal definition even if the value of `C(k)` doesn't change as a result.

Fortunately, perhaps, there is an easy way to create a temporary array to avoid aliasing: give the dummy argument `B` the `value` attribute.  You could even do the same to `A` and remove the workspace array.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the mistakes in my intents. Because of Vladimir F. comment I would change my declaration to: `integer, target, intent(inout) :: A(:), B(:), C(:)`. The compiler may not assume non overlapping memory anymore and the order of execution should be preserved. In this case `call merge(work(1 : half), A(half + 1:), A)`  should be a valid call in my understanding. I really would like to avoid the `value` attribute and temporary arrays.

Comment: Using `target, intent(inout)` removes the "no definition" constraint, but in this case I'd be rather worried about the logic.  What would you expect the result of the call to `merge` to be when `A=[1,1,0]` in `mergesort`?

Comment: My expectation is: If I have `work(: 2) = [1, 1]`, and `A(2 + 1:) == [0]` the call to `merge(work(:2), A(2 + 1 :), A)` will produce `A = [0, 1, 1]`, as long as the order of executions is not changed by the compiler.